# Species occurrence - from dots to 10X10km grid cells in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a map of species occurrences with dots, where each dot represents a registration of a species. I also have a 10x10km grid cell layer of the area. I want a map only containing grid cells where there is an overlap between the dots and the grid. Each grid has an ID.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your grid is a grid of individual polygons (as it sounds to be if each has an id) then use Vector => Analysis tools => Count points in polygon. This will create a second grid file (called "Count" if you don't change any defaults). Then you can display from the "Count" layer only those polygons whose count is greater than 0.

Comment: To add to Leigh's answer, the point and grid vector layers *must* be projected to the same Coordinate Reference System.